# Deleting a Record from MySQL Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, crud

There's something wrong with my codes and I'm unable to run it successfully. When I debug my Ajax code using *Google Developer tools*, Ajax *data parameter* has the value of the primary key (*uid*) but it seems it doesn't send *POST* request to *delete.php*. I've no idea what the problem is. 
Thanks for your helps and suggestions in advance!

index.php: Press Delete Button to Fire Ajax Code

```
<tbody>
<!--Populate HTML Table--> 
<?php if(!empty($records)) { 
foreach ($records as $record) {
?>
<tr>
    <td data-target="rowNum"></td>
    <td data-target="userId" style="display: none;">
        <?php echo $record['uid']; ?> 
    </td>
    <td data-target="firstname"><?php echo $record['first_name']; ?></td>   
    <td data-target="lastname"><?php echo $record['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td data-target="emailaddress"><?php echo $record['email_address']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btnEdit">Edit</button>
        <!--Press Delete Button to Fire Ajax Code-->
        <button class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Ajax Code: Send userId (Table Primary Key) as Data to Delete.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnDelete").click(function(){

        var userId = $(this).closest("tr").children("td[data-target=userId]").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: userId
        });

    });
});
```

delete.php:

```
<?php 

include 'database.php';

$conn->query("DELETE FROM Users WHERE uid = '$_POST['userId']'");

?>
```

Comment: You did not close your php tag on line 9

Comment: are you getting user id?

Comment: You should close with `?>`

Answer (score 0):

You pass your data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "delete.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: userId
});
```

`userId` value is probably just a scalar without key that you're trying to use in delete.php. So change this code to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "delete.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { userId: userId }
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: I edited my Ajax code snippet and replaced method .val() with .text() . I tried your solution bu it didn't work out.

Comment: @user283441, can you post output of var_dump for $_POST in delete.php?

Comment: Here is what I get when running var_dump($_POST) in my delete.php page: C:\wamp64\www\CRUD\delete.php:5:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Is this output when you send the data using AJAX?

Comment: No! I only typed down the code in my delete.php page and ran it! I know it was a stupid mistake sorry! I'm still not able to connect to my delete.php using ajax.

Comment: When I type var_dump($_POST) in my delete.php page then press button Delete, nothing shows! It seems my button doesn't send any request (using Ajax).

Comment: What does developer tools in your browser says? I mean "Network" tab.

Answer (score 0):

this might help, you are send data as text.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnDelete").click(function(){

        var userId = $(this).closest("tr").children("td[data-target=userId]").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'text/plain'
            data: {userId:userId}
        });

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get it to run the way you are trying to but here's a way that makes a bit more sense to me:

```
<tbody>
<!--Populate HTML Table--> 
<?php if(!empty($records)) { 
foreach ($records as $record) {
?>
<tr>
    <td data-target="rowNum"></td>
    <td data-target="firstname"><?php echo $record['first_name']; ?></td>   
    <td data-target="lastname"><?php echo $record['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td data-target="emailaddress"><?php echo $record['email_address']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btnEdit">Edit</button>
        <!--Press Delete Button to Fire Ajax Code-->
        <form class="deleteForm" method="POST">   
            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?= $record['uid'] ?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Then in JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deleteForm").on('submit', function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();  // Let jQuery prepare the data
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data
        });
        return false; // Cancel default

    });
});
```

Lastly:

```
<?php 

include 'database.php';
$userId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userId', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); //Assuming an ID is an int, in general be cautions of SQL injection.

if ($userId) {
    $conn->query("DELETE FROM Users WHERE uid = '$_POST['userId']'");
} else {
   http_response_code(400); // Missing the input
   die();
}


?>
```